# How to check the exit code of a Docker container run with the Jenkins Docker pipeline plugin `withRun()` method?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, docker-container, exit-code

In my Jenkins pipeline, I run a Docker container.
To take advantage of the automatic cleanup (stopping the Docker container), I use the Jenkins Docker plugin pipeline's `withRun()` method to run the container.
I noticed that the stage where the Docker container is run is always successful, regardless of the actual exit code of the Docker container.
This can be demonstrated with the following Docker image and Jenkins pipeline:

```
#! /bin/bash
# my_script

EXIT_CODE=${EXIT_CODE:-0}

exit $EXIT_CODE
```

```
# Dockerfile

FROM debian:10.3 as base

COPY ./my_script /usr/local/bin
```

```
// jenkinsfile

pipeline {
  agent any
  options { timestamps()}

  stages {
    stage('1') {
      steps {
        script {
          def img = 'controlled_exit:latest'
          def docker_image = docker.image(img)

          docker_image.withRun('-e EXIT_CODE=5', 'my_script') { }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The intent of the Jenkinsfile is to do `docker run -e EXIT_CODE=5 controlled_exit:latest my_script`, which returns the expected nonzero exit-code when run manually:

```
$ docker run -e EXIT_CODE=5 controlled_exit:latest my_script
$ echo $?
5
$
```

But, from the Jenkins pipeline's console log, I noticed that what it's actually doing is `docker run -d -e EXIT_CODE=5 controlled_exit:latest my_script`.
Note that the container is being run in the background, due to the `-d` option, which I assume is being unconditionally added by the `withRun()` function.

**Question: what is the recommended/idiomatic way to check the exit-code of Docker contains run with the the Jenkins Docker pipeline plugin `withRun()` method?**
Can you control `withRun()` to not run its Docker containers in the background?

I'm assuming that use of `withRun()` is recommended to avoid the need for explicit cleanup:

> More safely, you can use the withRun method, which automatically stops the container at the end of a block
> <sub>https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci/latest/pipelines/docker-workflow</sub>

...but I'd be okay with an answer that can explain why that need not be true.

What I've tried:
Reading Jenkin's `docker` Global Variable Reference documentation:

> The docker variable offers convenient access to Docker-related functions from a Pipeline script.
>
> Methods needing a Jenkins agent will implicitly run a node {…} block if you have not wrapped them in one. It is a good idea to enclose a block of steps which should all run on the same node in such a block yourself. (If using a Swarm server, or any other specific Docker server, this probably does not matter, but if you are using the default server on localhost it likely will.)
>
> Some methods return instances of auxiliary classes which serve as holders for an ID and which have their own methods and properties. Methods taking a body return any value returned by the body itself. Some method parameters are optional and are enclosed with []. Reference:
> Image.withRun[(args[, command])] {…}
> Like run but stops the container as soon as its body exits, so you do not need a try-finally block.
> <sub>http://{{jenkins_server}}/job/my_job/pipeline-syntax/globals#docker</sub>

...which does not address containers' exit codes.